# Are there any existing research in Voice Recognition that can distinguish voice from different people?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I just came up with an idea that I want to develop into an application to distinguish/auto detect voices from different people.

Sample use case: After training with Obama and Romney's data, the application would be able to detect whenever either one speak again (not necessary the same content from the training data)

I am wondering if there are any existing research on this. (I don't know how to search for this. I tried a couple keywords and got no significant results.)

If not, what is a good way to start? How to choose features, data representation, models, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [Speaker recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_recognition) on Wikipedia which in turn linked to [An overview of text-independent speaker recognition: From features to supervectors](http://cs.joensuu.fi/pages/tkinnu/webpage/pdf/speaker_recognition_overview.pdf) (Kinnunen, Li, 2010).

From the abstract of the paper:

> This paper gives an overview of automatic speaker recognition technology, with an emphasis on text-independent recognition. Speaker recognition has been studied actively for several decades. We give an overview of both the classical and the state-of-the-art methods.